# Getting following error while writing any git reflow commands

Tags: git, github, reflow

Getting following error while writing any git reflow commands

This is what I get during executing `git reflow setup`.

`````
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/dsl.rb:226:in `verify_unused_in_option': f has already been specified as a switch in the command deliver (ArgumentError)
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/dsl.rb:220:in `block in verify_unused'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/dsl.rb:218:in `each'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/dsl.rb:218:in `verify_unused'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/dsl.rb:117:in `switch'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/command_support.rb:78:in `switch'
from /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/git_reflow-0.4.1/lib/git_reflow/commands/deliver.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/dsl.rb:199:in `command'
from /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/git_reflow-0.4.1/lib/git_reflow/commands/deliver.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/app.rb:312:in `block in load_commands'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/app.rb:309:in `each'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/app.rb:309:in `load_commands'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/app.rb:38:in `block in commands_from'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/app.rb:36:in `each'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gli-2.12.2/lib/gli/app.rb:36:in `commands_from'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/git_reflow-0.4.1/bin/git-reflow:24:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/git-reflow:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/git-reflow:23:in `<main>'````
`````

Comment: I'm a contributor to git-reflow.  In the future, please open up an issue as we can respond to you faster ;-)

Have you tried upgrading to the latest version? `0.4.2`?

Comment: @codenamev looks like I did re-install and it worked. Getting another error here. Logged Issues [here](https://github.com/reenhanced/gitreflow/issues/94).